# How to set background colour for header and footer in Stack and Tab Navigator in react-native

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native

I have set header and footer using stack and tab Navigator. But the backgroundcolour of the header and footer is in grey.

How to change the background colour in header and footer navigation?

Comment: Please post relevant code snippets along with your question.

Comment: tabBarOptions: {
    showLabel: false,

  },
  tabBarComponent: TabBarBottom,
  backgroundColor: 'white',
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  animationEnabled: false,
  swipeEnabled: false,
});

Comment: Above is my code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

Please try using style as follows:

```
tabBarOptions: {
  style: {
    backgroundColor: 'white'
  }
}
```

or add below code in your screen:

```
static navigationOptions = (navigation) => {
      return {
          headerStyle: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
      }
  }
```